# Jenkins Fargate plugin : How to Limit scaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, aws-fargate

I am running jenkins on AWS and i am using Jenkins fargate plugin to submit jobs to agents.
But looking at the setup, i donot see any option to limit scaling of agent workers. So if i submit 200 jobs then it will scale up 200 agent tasks which has cost implications.

Can someone please advise if there are any parameters which can be setup to limit amount of scaling for jenkins fargate agents.

Jenkins fargate plugin used : https://plugins.jenkins.io/amazon-ecs/